# Sort an object by each value in a sub object

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, underscore.js

I'm trying to sort an object that is being used to display standings in a racing league. I need to be able to sort the drivers by not points but past finishing positions. If drivers end up on the same number of points then previous positions will be looked at starting at 1st place, going down to the last place which is dependant on how many drivers are in the league. The object which has all the drivers in looks something like this:

```
var standings = [{
    driver: "Bob",
    points: 45,
    positions: {
        0: 1,
        1: 0,
        2: 1,
        3: 2,
        4: 0
    }
}, {
    driver: "Mandy",
    points: 17,
    positions: {
        0: 0,
        1: 2,
        2: 4,
        3: 0,
        4: 1
    }
}, {
    driver: "Robert",
    points: 24,
    positions: {
        0: 0,
        1: 1,
        2: 5,
        3: 3,
        4: 0
    }
}];
```

The positions object is number of times they've finished in a particular position, the key indicating the position so key 0 = 1st Place, key 1 = 2nd Place.

The number of key->values in the positions object will vary with the number of drivers in a league.

What I've been trying to do is work out how I can use underscore _.sortby to sort it first by the lowest position, working it's way up to 1st and then finally by the points but I can't seem to find a way to do this - running a loop which runs the sortby function on the object for every item in the positions object doesn't seem to work - it seems to just reset.

My initial attempt that doesn't seem to work is:

```
var driverCount = 3;
for (i = 0; i < driverCount; i++) {
    standings = _.sortBy(standings, 'positions['+i+']').reverse();
}
standings = _.sortBy(standings, 'points').reverse();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: That `standings` object you have isn't valid JavaScript syntax

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your task, but what I can see from you code is, that you are overwriting the `standings` value, and on the and you have just the last result, try using `standings[i] = ` instead

Comment: @Cerbrus Oops, just updated it more like it should be. Though I didn't see any errors in my browser for how the positions object is setup (and it did seem to be sorting if I remove the for loop) I'm noticing that javascript syntax checks are showing it as incorrect.

Comment: @Sheki I'm trying to sort my object by multiple values. I want to sort it by each of the keys in the 'positions' object and then finally by the number of points. 

"If drivers are tied on points, positions are decided on results countback. Wins are compared, and the driver with most wins is classified ahead. If wins are equal, second places are looked at, and so on."

I've noticed you can chain _.sortby but I don't know if I can do that with a for loop as different leagues will have different numbers of drivers so I don't know how to pass the fields to sortby.

Comment: I would change the `positions` object to `[{key:1,value:0},{key:2,value:2}]` and so one, sou you can say something like this than`_.sortBy(positions,'value')'`

Answer (score 0):

Change your object to:

```
    var standings = [{
        driver: "Bob",
        points: 45,
        positions: [
            {key:0, valeu:1},
            {key:1, valeu:0},
            {key:2, valeu:1},
            {key:3, valeu:2},
            {key:4, valeu:0}
        ]
    }, {
        driver: "Mandy",
        points: 17,
        positions: [
            {key:0, valeu:0},
            {key:1, valeu:2},
            {key:2, valeu:4},
            {key:3, valeu:0},
            {key:4, valeu:1}
        ]
    }, {
        driver: "Robert",
        points: 24,
        positions:[
             {key:0, valeu:0},
             {key:1, valeu:1},
             {key:2, valeu:5},
             {key:3, valeu:3},
             {key:4, valeu:0}
       ]
    }];
```

than use sort function to sort the positions and standings:

```
for (i = 0; i < standings.length; i++) { 
    standings[i].positions = standings[i].positions.sort(()=>{ 
    if (a.value == b.value)
        return 0;
    if (a.value > b.value)
        return -1;
    else
        return 1;
   })
}
```

than sort the rest of the array:

```
standings.sort((a,b)=>{
    if (a.points == b.points)
        return 0;
    if (a.points > b.points)
        return -1;
    else
        return 1;
});
```

Didn't test the code, but you understand the idea

Comment: This doesn't seem to achieve what I'm after - it just sorts each drivers positions array, then sorts the standings by points, rather than sorting the standings by each drivers previous positions, then by points.

Comment: That's why I said, am not sure I understand your task, what's the "drivers previous positions"?

Answer (score 0):

You have a composite sorting function.

I would use something like:

```
_sortBy(standings, (o) => o.points+Math.min(... _.pluck(o.positions, 'value')))); // wtach out your key is missspelled valeu
```